# How to deal with cascading observable

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, nestjs

I have difficulties to grasp the way things works with observables.
I'm developing an API that retrieves a "Person" who'll have multiple properties and two "Parent".
I'm retrieving these objects with the mssql module, which returns observables.
My issue here is that when I get the Observable, I'm not able to get a "Parent" object to fill the "Person" (as I'm getting another Observable) that my function returns.

I understood that the map operator allows me to edit the emitted value to fill the Parents fields with the help of the Person ID.
But it seems the two Observable cannot be subscribed in the map operator: my function returns the Observable without waiting for the parents to be filled.

```
return this.SQLService.GetPerson().pipe(
  map((p: any): Person => {
    // This fills the Person object from the db returned object
    let returnValue = new Person(p);
    this.SQLService.GetParent(returnValue.ID).pipe(
      map((parentObj: any): Parent => { return new Parent(parentObj); })
    ).subscribe(
      (parentInstance: Parent): void => {returnValue.Parent1 = parentInstance;}
    );
  return returnValue;
})
```

Coming from synchronous development, I'd expect my returnValue to actually return a Person with a Person.Parent1 field containing a parent.
In the end, I can get the Person, but without the Parent1 field. (and no error message)

Comment: You're probably looking for `mergeMap` or `concatMap` operators

Comment: @martin: I don't really understand how to use it. If I put it after the GetPerson map operator (which pass, if I understood everything, an Observable of Person to the next operator), how can I return the Parent to put in the Person?
Do I have to create an intermediate object with both object in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) here.

Then when you map your result from `GetParent` you can return an object with the response from both `GetParent` and `GetPerson`.

```
return this.SQLService.GetPerson().pipe(
  switchMap((p: any): Person => {
    // This fills the Person object from the db returned object
    let returnValue = new Person(p);
    return this.SQLService.GetParent(returnValue.ID).pipe(
      map((parentObj: any): Parent => { return { parent: new Parent(parentObj), returnValue }; })
    );
  }),

).subscribe(({ parent, returnValue }): void => {returnValue.Parent1 = parentInstance;});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works, not sure though how switchMap is different from concatMap, but both works that way.

Comment: Also if you have any lead on how shall we deal with arrays in it, I'd take it: My Person will be an array afterward, but simple map doesn't allow me to loop through the GetParent calls

Comment: This may be helpful: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

Comment: Also, if you are interested in an overview of RxJS Observables, I recently wrote a blog post myself: http://willtaylor.blog/rxjs-observables-hot-cold-explained/

Comment: I'll read your article. I think I miss something as so far, it seems to me that observables are not meant to be on the backend, where most of the time we don't need async operations...